# Magento2 REST API Error 'Class does not exist'

Tags: magento2, module, rest-api, web-services

I've created a test Magento 2.0.2 REST web service based on Alan's blog: http://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/

I'm using Postman to call the custom web service and get the following error:

```
"message": "Class  does not exist",
  "code": -1,
  "trace": "#0 P:\\wwwroot\\Magento202_com_loc\\Web\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor.php(128): ReflectionClass->__construct('')\n#1 P:\\wwwroot\\Magento202_com_loc\\Web\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor.php(262): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray(NULL, '30')\n#2 P:\\wwwroot\\Magento202_com_loc\\Web\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor.php(99): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->convertValue('30', NULL)\n#3 P:\\wwwroot\\Magento202_com_loc\\Web\\vendor\\magento\\module-webapi\\Controller\\Rest.php(262): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Test\\\\Calculator...', 'add', Array)\n#4 P:\\wwwroot\\Magento202_com_loc\\Web\\vendor\\magento\\module-webapi\\Controller\\Rest.php(160): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#5 P:\\wwwroot\\Magento202_com_loc\\Web\\var\\generation\\Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#6 P:\\wwwroot\\Magento202_com_loc\\Web\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Http.php(115): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#7 P:\\wwwroot\\Magento202_com_loc\\Web\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#8 P:\\wwwroot\\Magento202_com_loc\\Web\\index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#9 {main}"
```

I can successfully call Magento out-of-the-box REST web services.

app/code/Test/Calculator/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Test_Calculator',
__DIR__
);
```

app/code/Test/Calculator/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Calculator" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Test/Calculator/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

    <route url="/V1/calculator/add/:num1/:num2" method="GET">
        <service class="Test\Calculator\Api\CalculatorInterface" method="add"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

app/code/Test/Calculator/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Test\Calculator\Api\CalculatorInterface" type="Test\Calculator\Model\Calculator" />
</config>
```

app/code/Test/Calculator/Api/CalculatorInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Calculator\Api;

interface CalculatorInterface
{
    public function add($num1, $num2);
}
```

app/code/Test/Calculator/Model/Calculator.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Calculator\Model;

use Test\Calculator\Api\CalculatorInterface;

class Calculator implements CalculatorInterface
{
    public function add($num1, $num2) {
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}
```

REST url that returns the error:

```
http://local.magento202.com:81/index.php/rest/V1/calculator/add/30/70
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A DocBlock is required in app/code/Test/Calculator/Api/CalculatorInterface.php as described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/docblock-standard-general.html

```
<?php

namespace Test\Calculator\Api;

interface CalculatorInterface
{
    /**
     * Add two numbers.
     *
     * @param int $num1
     * @param int $num2
     * @return int
     */
    public function add($num1, $num2);
}
```

Comment: I was receiving the the same error, because i used @params instead of "@param". Magento 2 is too strict in code standards :P

Comment: what should i write as return value if i want return json array

Comment: [at]return array               @Bhupendra Jadeja

Comment: @AltafHussain I know it has been 2 years, but it has nothing to do with coding standards, is uses reflection to do validation, so it it can't find "@param" it will just break point blank. It's like you set $a and later want to it to use as $b but php standards are too strict

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. Thank you. I would have never thought that would have mattered but it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 15):

In my case problem was that I used "use" clausule in interface. Magento DocBlockReflection could not handle that and was searching for interface without full namespace. So for example in bellow code:

```
use My\Namespace\ExampleObjectInterface
interface ExampleObjectRepositoryInterface
{
/**
 * xyz
 * @param int $id
 * @return ExampleObjectInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function getById($id);
}
```

I needed to remove "use" clausule:

```
interface ExampleObjectRepositoryInterface
{
/**
 * xyz
 * @param int $id
 * @return \My\Namespace\ExampleObjectInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function getById($id);
}
```

Comment: omg, you have saved my life. I was debugging this for hours. Why is magento framework so hard to use :(

Comment: Insane this was my case also. surely it should be valid with Aliases!

Comment: This solved my issue on Magento 2.4.6.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the checklist if you struggling with same issue:

1. Service interfaces should be in `Api` folder.
2. Dto interfaces should be in `Api/Data` folder.
3. All interface methods should be type hinted. (Argument types, return types)
4. Imports should not be used. Specify a full namespace path for class.
5. ALL interfaces should have the correct PHPDOC.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Make sure below command executed successfully. Don't interrupt or hit any API call. After execution your issue will be resolved. Worked for me.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, It seemed that Magento DocBlockReflection could not find the API interface and class since it was in the root folder of my Plugin, I added my interface in the Api folder and my class in the Model folder and it worked!